# Close Settings App Programmatically on iPhone using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, settings

How would I close the Settings App programatically and navigate back to the original app that open the Settings App?  Thanks

Comment: You have no access on OS Settings, user should return to your app manually or by a tap on return button provide by OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specifically navigate back to the app that opened `Settings.app`, or any other app for that matter.

You can **only** navigate *to* specific apps using their URL schemes, if they have defined one.